# How t form complex xpath?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am new to selenium and trying to form complex xpath for my project. I have tried and already verified multiple solutions but none of them are working correctly. Kindly have a look and let me know your valuable feedback

Tried solutions

```
1. //div[@id='agree']//following-sibling::br
2. //div[@id='agree']
```

HTML

```
<div id="agree">
<label class="Control-label">Privacy Policy and Terms of Conditions</label>
<br style xpath="1">
Your personal information provided to us will be used
<a href="/privacy/statment" title="privacy policy">privacy policy</a>
"."
<br style xpath="2">
<br style xpath="3">
<a href="terms condition" title="terms condition">terms condition</a>
<br style xpath="4">
<br style xpath="5">
<a href="terms condition" title="terms condition">terms condition</a>
```

Expected solution:

```
Your personal information provided to us will be used privacy policy.
```

Comment: Which Selenium client are you using? Java/Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just an alternative options.

In selenium If you are using java you can get either `text` property of the `div` tag or `textContent` attribute of the `div` tag and then do split lines.

If you use **Text** property.Try below code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='agree']")));
String text=element.getText();
String[] lines = text.split("\\r?\\n");
System.out.println(lines[1]);
```

If you use **textContent** Attribute try this.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);         
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='agree']")));
String text=element.getAttribute("textContent");
String[] lines = text.split("\\r?\\n");
System.out.println(lines[3] + " " +lines[4].trim() + lines[5]);
```

Comment: Ohh ...great 1s one is working for me and the second one is failing due to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException so I am ignoring second one. Thank you @kunduK

Comment: Glad to help you.Please Upvote the answer this will help future readers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works with selenium, and if this is indeed your desired output, but try this xpath expression:

```
//div/text()[3] | //div/a[1]/text()
```

or, depending on your implementation

```
//div/text()[3], //div/a[1]/text()
```

[note that, again, depending on your implementation, the `position()` of `text()` in the first part of the expression may be `1` or `2`.]

In any case, it should output:

```
Your personal information provided to us will be used
privacy policy
```

Comment: This works with regular XPath but XPath in Selenium won't return text nodes.